# neo4j cypher query returns no rows, lists comparison issues

Tags: list, neo4j, comparison, cypher

Dears,
I'm facing an issue with Cypher syntax (I'm using Neo3J 3.0.7),

Here is my query:

```
with ['{"id":"401"}'] as s2
match(cpp:CPP) unwind cpp.property_suppliers as s1 with s1,s2,cpp 
where all(x IN s2 where x IN s1) return cpp
```

It returns no row despite the fact my db contains this node:

```
node_status ACTIF
role    [CPP]
property_productid  r001
property_quantity   320000.0
modelNodeId node_6efc6f94-6864-d162-897f-4000f8c0cb77_c__a_k__b
property_suppliers  [{"id":"401"},{"id":"402"}]
ui_position_in_anyView  { "position" : { "x" : 100.0, "y" : 100.0 } }
id  node_6efc6f94-6864-d162-897f-4000f8c0cb77
type    {http://fr.emac.gind/c2net/objective}Plan
property_deadline   1500388263
ui_dimension_in_anyView { "dimension" : { "width" : 53.04, "height" : 53.04 } }
```

As you can see, my will is to retrieve 'cpp' nodes that have (at least) the suppliers of the given list 's2'.

I suppose I have some troubles with string-related castings? 
Is the unwind necessary for the s1 list? 
The query without unwind:

```
with ['{"id":"401"}'] as s2
match(cpp:CPP) with s2,cpp 
where all(x IN s2 where x IN cpp.property_suppliers) return cpp
```

returns also no rows

I would appreciate any help, I did not find similar problems for now.
Best
Julien.

Comment: How are you creating a node with `property_suppliers =  [{"id":"401"},{"id":"402"}]` since collections containing mixed types can not be stored in properties?

Comment: The node info you provided looks like it was generated by your software, and probably does not represent what is actually stored in the DB. What does this Cypher query return: `MATCH (cpp:CPP) RETURN cpp.property_suppliers LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your answers. I think the software I use stores the property_suppliers as a String actually. 

Here is the response for the query:

`[{"id":"401"}, {"id":"402"}]`

I'm working on a solution in which I only store an array of int instead of json objects.